# what are the most common use case scenarios for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems like npm is the most common use of node.js.  Would you estimate that 80%+ of node.js users only use the npm functionality?  What do you think are the most common use case scenarios for node.js outside of npm?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be confused about what node.js and npm actually are, hopefully I can help clear this up.

Node.js is a javascript run-time environment. Originally, javascript was used mainly, is not exclusively, for client side scripting fro webpages. In 2009, Ryan Dahl released node.js, which essentially allowed developers who were very comfortable with Javascript (Standardized ECMAScript) to use javascript in a server environment. Prior to this, a developer would use other technologies (PHP, Java, ect). Node.js allowed the developers to work with javascript both server-side and client-side.

NPM, or Node Package Manager is essentially an "add-on" to Node.js. It is an application that allows users to specify packages, that is, modules that someone wrote and published, to be used in their own projects.

So to try to answer your questions:

> Would you estimate that 80%+ of node.js users only use the npm functionality?

No, Using solely the npm functionality would never REALLY accomplish anything, all NPM does is download some files to your computer.

> What do you think are the most common use case scenarios for node.js outside of npm?

Node is used for sever-side scripting. Arguably the most popular use is to provide a back-end functionality to web apps.

Comment: So node.js is some type of platform. Grunt has plugins.  Would it be accurate to describe npm as a node "plugin"?

Comment: If the most popular use is to provide back-end functionality to web apps, then I'm guessing that node is used a lot to serve up REST services?